# Connect to google analytics with HTTPS authentication with MuleSoft's

Tags: https, oauth-2.0, google-analytics-api, mule-studio

I'm trying to connect to Google Analytics in MuleSoft's.

I do following the [explantion on in this](https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-user-guide/v/3.6/authentication-in-http-requests#oauth-authentication-with-authorization-code-grant-type). I got the example working.

And this is my code for Google:

```
<http:listener-config name="HTTP_Listener_Configuration" host="0.0.0.0" port="8081" doc:name="HTTP Listener Configuration" />

<http:request-config name="HTTP_Request_Configuration" protocol="HTTPS" host="www.googleapis.com" port="443" basePath="/analytics/v3" doc:name="HTTP Request Configuration">
    <oauth2:authorization-code-grant-type clientId="145367832290-fj9v2rk3u0np7grbubseb08fnb8bkqkm.apps.googleusercontent.com" clientSecret="90XF6uj4Ud3nn0nGrGo1njIY" redirectionUrl="http://localhost:8082/callback" tokenManager-ref="Token_Manager_Config">
        <oauth2:authorization-request authorizationUrl="https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/v2/auth" localAuthorizationUrl="http://localhost:8082/login" scopes="https://www.googleapis.com/auth/analytics">
            <oauth2:custom-parameters>
                <oauth2:custom-parameter paramName="access_type" value="offline" />
            </oauth2:custom-parameters>
        </oauth2:authorization-request>
        <oauth2:token-request tokenUrl="https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v4/token">
            <oauth2:token-response accessToken="#[json:access_token]" refreshToken="#[json:refresh_token]" expiresIn="#[json:expires_in]">
                <oauth2:custom-parameter-extractor paramName="token_type" value="#[json:token_type]" />
            </oauth2:token-response>
        </oauth2:token-request>
    </oauth2:authorization-code-grant-type>
    <http:raml-api-configuration location="api.raml" />
</http:request-config>
<flow name="oauthgoogleFlow">
    <http:listener config-ref="HTTP_Listener_Configuration" path="/" doc:name="HTTP" allowedMethods="GET" />
    <http:request config-ref="HTTP_Request_Configuration" path="/data/ga" method="GET" doc:name="HTTP">
        <http:request-builder>
            <http:query-param paramName="ids" value="ga:134790070" />
            <http:query-param paramName="start_date" value="30daysAgo" />
            <http:query-param paramName="end_date" value="yesterday" />
            <http:query-param paramName="metrics" value="ga:users" />
        </http:request-builder>
    </http:request>
</flow>
```

Depending how I import the access token, refresh token. I get a different error:

If I do Ask the tokens with:

> Access token = #[json:access_token] & Refresh token =#[json:refresh_token],...

I get the error: `Response code 400 mapped as failure.`

If I ask it like:

> Access token = #[payload.'access_token'] & Refresh token = #[payload.'refresh_token']

I get: `Failed getting access token or refresh token from token URL response. See logs for details.`

Anyone see the problem?

Comment: Hey having hard time in find GA API RAML in Mule. Can you point me to the url to download the same .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

never mind idiotic mistake! The code checks out. the only mistake I made was:

paramName="start_date" => paramName="start-date"

paramName="end_date" => paramName="end-date"